# Replace anchor link with specific content using regex

Tags: regex

I have many anchor links in a page and would like to replace all link to "#", it is the purpose to avoid user to jump into another site during a demonstration.

For example:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://example.com/home/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Demo</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="ahref" cid="1" href="http://www.example.com/1/">Demo 1</a>Demo 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="ahref" cid="2" href="http://www.example.com/2/">Demo 1</a>Demo 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="ahref" cid="3" href="http://www.example.com/3/">Demo 1</a>Demo 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="ahref" cid="4" href="http://www.example.com/4/">Demo 1</a>Demo 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I search all `<a href="....">` and replace them with `<a href="#">` but excluding all other attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

search:  `(a.*?href\s*=\s*)['"].*?['"]`

replace with: `\1"#"`

Comment: Very good aelor ... this Work successfully (y)

Comment: You should force a `<` before the `a` tag and a space after it to avoid mispicks. Maybe like this: `(<a\s.*?href\s*=\s*)['"].*?['"]`